# Setup MX records from command line

Tags: dns, devops

There should be an easy way to find answer to that question but I actually have struggled a lot and didn't find one.

My domain DNS are pointing to my server where I have Apache Vhost configured but I want my MX record point to other domain. All of the answer I found was to use some sort of GUI manager like Cpanel or DirectAdmin but I have none of them nor I feel like I need one.

But how the heck can I change my MX records. Which files should I modify. Something in my VirtualHost settings? I'm at the complete loss with this one.

Comment: What OS and what nameserver do you use?

Comment: Apache does not manage your DNS MX resource records. Some DNS servers have a CLI, some do not. Some DNS servers support importing records in bind format. Edit your question with details on the DNS server for your domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you run Linux/Unix OS and bind9 nameserver and your nameserver is primary for your domain.

For Linux.
Check files `/etc/named.conf` `/etc/named.conf.local` looking for the paragraph like:

```
zremove one "yourdomain" {
    type master;
    file "/path/to/some/file";
```

For BSD OS check file `/usr/local/etc/named.conf`

Edit the file that contains the description of your zone (`/usr/local/etc/named.conf`)

You will see the lines that look like
`nnnn  IN MX mm mail.server.hostname.` where `n` and `m` are digits.
Replace `mail.server.hostname.` with name of your mail host(s). Note the trailing. Add/remove records if you have more/less mail servers than currently.
You have also to modify `SOA` record increasing value of `serial` field
Restart named.

BTW. You can info about DNS server configuration from man pages: `named (8)`  and  `named.conf (5)`